# DATE_ADD or DATE_DIFF error when grouping dates in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Try and search as I might, I still cannot figure this out and although https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add has assisted a bit, I am still stuck. I am trying to group dates into weeks but keep getting either one of the two errors below the code.

```
day         bitcoin_total   dash_total
2009-01-03  1               0
2009-01-09  14              0
2009-01-10  61              0
```

The desirable outcome would be the date at the start of the week (could be Monday or Sunday, whichever)

```
day         bitcoin_total   dash_total
2008-12-28  1               0
2009-01-04  75              0
```

This seems to be a common question but most of the answers are for T-SQL and not standard SQL. My date column is type `Date` but that is the return type so that should not be a problem.

```
DATE_ADD(week, DATE_DIFF(week, 0, day), 0) Date
FROM
my_table
GROUP BY
DATE_ADD(week, DATE_DIFF(week, 0, day), 0) 
ORDER BY
DATE_ADD(week, DATE_DIFF(week, 0, day), 0)
```

I am getting a `Unrecognized name: week at [2:10]` error with the above code or `Error: Expected INTERVAL expression at [2:29]` if I change the `date_expression` in the DATE_ADD function to, say, `DATE "2009-01-01"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(day, WEEK) AS day, 
  SUM(bitcoin_total) AS bitcoin_total, 
  SUM(dash_total) AS dash_total
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY day
```

If to apply to sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2009-01-03' day, 1 bitcoin_total, 0 dash_total UNION ALL
  SELECT '2009-01-09', 14, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2009-01-10', 61, 0 
)
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(day, WEEK) AS day, 
  SUM(bitcoin_total) AS bitcoin_total, 
  SUM(dash_total) AS dash_total
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY day
```

output will be

```
Row day         bitcoin_total   dash_total   
1   2008-12-28  1               0    
2   2009-01-04  75              0
```

Comment: consider also voting up if answer helped :o)

Comment: I have/I do. Thanks for the quick response. Just to clarify, is BigQuery Standard SQL it's own language?

Comment: it is based on the SQL 2011 standard, with extensions for querying nested and repeated data and many more

Comment: Ok I was searching solutions for SQL 2011, thanks again.