# Group days into weeks with totals PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I recently had help with a similar query [DATE_ADD or DATE_DIFF error when grouping dates in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347965/date-add-or-date-diff-error-when-grouping-dates-in-bigquery/57348769?noredirect=1#comment101185948_57348769) but I was wondering how to do this in PySpark as I am rather new

```
day         bitcoin_total   dash_total
2009-01-03  1               0
2009-01-09  14              0
2009-01-10  61              0
```

The desirable outcome would be the date at the start of the week (could be Monday or Sunday, whichever)

```
day         bitcoin_total   dash_total
2008-12-28  1               0
2009-01-04  75              0
```

The below code is returning weeks by numbers and the totals seems off. I cannot seem to replicate the total that .agg(sum()) is returning and I cannot even add the second total (dash_total). I tried `.col("dash_total")` Is there a way to group days into weeks?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import weekofyear, sum

(df
    .groupBy(weekofyear("day").alias("date_by_week"))
    .agg(sum("bitcoin_total"))
    .orderBy("date_by_week")
    .show())
```

I am running Spark on Databricks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this approach using **`date_sub,next_day`** functions in spark.

**Explanation:**

```
date_sub(
        next_day(col("day"),"sunday"), //get next sunday date
   7)) //substract week from the date
```

### Example:

**`In pyspark:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = sc.parallelize([("2009-01-03","1","0"),("2009-01-09","14","0"),("2009-01-10","61","0")]).toDF(["day","bitcoin_total","dash_total"])
df.withColumn("week_strt_day",date_sub(next_day(col("day"),"sunday"),7)).groupBy("week_strt_day").agg(sum("bitcoin_total").cast("int").alias("bitcoin_total"),sum("dash_total").cast("int").alias("dash_total")).orderBy("week_strt_day").show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|week_strt_day|bitcoin_total|dash_total|
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|   2008-12-28|            1|         0|
|   2009-01-04|           75|         0|
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

**`In scala:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df=Seq(("2009-01-03","1","0"),("2009-01-09","14","0"),("2009-01-10","61","0")).toDF("day","bitcoin_total","dash_total") 
df.withColumn("week_strt_day",date_sub(next_day('day,"sunday"),7)).groupBy("week_strt_day").agg(sum("bitcoin_total").cast("int").alias("bitcoin_total"),sum("dash_total").cast("int").alias("dash_total")).orderBy("week_strt_day").show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|week_strt_day|bitcoin_total|dash_total|
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|   2008-12-28|            1|         0|
|   2009-01-04|           75|         0|
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if there are more than just the three dates rather than inputting each date and column total that you want included in the dataframe? Say I want to include 6 years of dates, would PySpark do that? The below did this in sql.                             `SELECT DATE_TRUNC(day, WEEK) AS day, 
  SUM(bitcoin_total) AS bitcoin_total, 
  SUM(dash_total) AS dash_total
FROM project.dataset.table
GROUP BY day`

Comment: Nevermind, you just skip the sc.parallelize line and it works. Thanks again, big up.